# how to databind three levels nested repeaters

Tags: asp.net

I have three nested repeaters, I have databind the first and the second but I can't figure out how to databind the third one my here is my markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="mainMenuRepeater" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

            <li><a title='<%#Eval("post_name")%>' id='<%#Eval("id")%>'  href='<%#ResolveUrl(Eval("post_permalink"))%>'><%# Eval("post_name")%></a>
                <asp:Repeater ID="subMenuRepeater" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>

                 <li>
                 <a href='<%#ResolveUrl(Eval("post_permalink"))%>'><%# Eval("post_name")%></a>

                     <asp:Repeater ID="sub_subMenuRepeater" runat="server">
                      <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><a href='<%#ResolveUrl(Eval("post_permalink"))%>'><%# Eval("post_name")%></a></li>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                      <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                     </asp:Repeater>
                 </li>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></li>
            <br style="clear: left" />
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

And below is my code that databind the second repeater named subMenuRepeater:

```
Protected Sub mainMenuRepeater_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles mainMenuRepeater.ItemDataBound
        Try
            If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

                'Dim dv As DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
                Dim ad As Int32 = CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "id").ToString(), Int32)
                Dim db As iwebmalldatacontextDataContext = New iwebmalldatacontextDataContext()
                Dim menus = From m In db.iwebmall_posts
                            Where m.post_type = "page" And m.post_status = 1 And m.post_parent = ad Order By m.post_menu_order
                            Select m.post_permalink, m.post_name, m.id

                Dim subMenu As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("subMenuRepeater"), Repeater)
                If menus.Count > 0 Then
                    With subMenu
                        .DataSource = menus
                        .DataBind()
                    End With
                End If

            End If




        Catch ex As Exception
            '  Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Please how can I databind the third on named sub_subMenuRepeater. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the same process as you have for your first nested repeater.

When the outer repeater's ItemDataBound event is called, you fetch the current Item and then bind properties for the nested repeater.

If you subscribe to the  ItemDataBound event of the nested repeater you could then databind the subnested repeater.

Comment: There is no way the ItemDataBound Event of a repeater sitting inside a repeater can be generated. If there is a way please let me know.

Comment: Ìn your code you get the submenu repeater. You could subscribe to the ItemDataBoundEvent before calling DataBind()